# Matlab Bar Graph containing 2 bars

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to make bar with containing 2 bars. Below is the code to make a single bar graph from an excel file. However, idk how to make a bar graph containing 2 bars. I  need to take data from 2 excel files. 1 is Locations vs NO2 and other one is Locations vs SO2. The locations are the same, but I need to compare NO2 and SO2. Can anyone help me out?

```
Airpollution = readtable ('Location vs No2.xlsx');
x = categorical(Airpollution{:,1});
y = Airpollution{:,2};
bar(x,y)
xlabel('Location');
ylabel('Concentration of No2');
title('Location vs Max concentration of No2');
```

Comment: The documentation for `bar` has lots of examples. Did you look there? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, since I don't have access to your data. But since you are saying you want 2 bars, which I am guessing are 
bar1=Airpollution{:,1} and bar2=Airpollution{:,2}

So you would need to combine them as your x (but in different rows):
x = [Airpollution{:,1}';Airpollution{:,2}']

Now try plotting bar(x)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how... I found this some days ago somewhere in google:

```
figure(1);
[dummy, t] = hist([one;two], numBin);
nx = hist(one, t); % Sort x into bins.
nx = transpose(nx/sum(nx));
ny = hist(two, t); % Sort y into bins.
ny = transpose(ny/sum(ny));
bar(t, [nx, ny]);
```